# Failed Login CLearOS webconfig

Tags: linux, authentication, centos, web-config, clearos

I have some problem: yesterday I overplayed with chown and totally change all file permissions. I can login into SSH, but the webconfig say failed login.

What I need to check and do in this situation?

Thanks a lot and waiting for answer :)

P.S. Sorry for terrible English.

Answer (score 0):

finally re-install ClearOS is the solution